# Nested not templated class inside a template class C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, friend, class-template

here is my code

head.h

```
template <class T>
class Ext;

template <class T>
void fun(const Ext<T>&);

template <class T>
class Ext {
    friend void fun<T>(const Ext<T>&);

   private:
    class Inner;

    Inner* p;
};

template <class T>
void fun2(const typename Ext<T>::Inner&);

template <class T>
class Ext<T>::Inner {
    friend class Ext<T>;
    friend void fun<T>(const Ext<T>&);
    friend void fun2<T>(const typename Ext<T>::Inner&);

   private:
    Inner* q;
    int a;
    Inner() : a(1) {}
};

template <class T>
void fun2(const typename Ext<T>::Inner& i) {
    std::cout << i.a << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void fun(const Ext<T>& e) {
    typename Ext<T>::Inner y;
    y.a = 3;
    fun2<T>(y);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Ext<int> x;
    fun(x);
}
```

g++ and (look below) clang give an

```
class Ext<int>::Inner’ is private within this context
```

So my question is : Is there a way to do this without making the inner class public?
And why if i replace fun anf fun2 with an overload operator<< then it compiles even with inner class private (ONLY WITH CLANG)? like this

head.h

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Ext;

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Ext<T>&);

template <class T>
class Ext {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const Ext<T>&);

   private:
    class Inner;

    Inner* p;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const typename Ext<T>::Inner&);

template <class T>
class Ext<T>::Inner {
    friend class Ext<T>;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const typename Ext<T>::Inner&);

   private:
    Inner* q;
    int a;
    Inner() : a(1) {}
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Ext<T>::Inner& n) {
    return os << n.a << " ";
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Ext<T>& t) {
    os << "[ ";
    operator<< <T>(os, *(t.p));
    os << "] ";
    return os;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Ext<int> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

i tried to compile with diffrent compilers but nothing works if i dont compile with clang and in that case its only compiles when the funcion is an overload of an operator

Comment: You need make class template `Ext` also a friend. Additionally you need to add `template<typename U>` to each of the friend declarations. This is explained in the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77464038/12002570). After making these changes the program will [work](https://godbolt.org/z/EfroEGz3x) in all compilers.

Comment: Also I would recommend asking only one question per post. The second code snippet should be asked as a different question imo. C++ is an insanely complicated language, so trying to understand it by trial and error is not the right way to learn it. Also, a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without making the inner class public?

Yes, but there are several problems with the code all of which are explained and [solved](https://godbolt.org/z/EfroEGz3x) below.

**First**, `friend`ship is not associative in C++. This means that you need to add a *friend template declaration* for `fun2` inside the class template `Ext` as shown in the code below.

**Second**, the friend declaration that you currently have are *non-template friend declarations*. But since `fun` and `fun2` are templates, you will need to change these to **friend template declarations** which is done by adding `template<typename U>` in the code shown below.

The comments are also added in the below program to make it easier to spot the changes:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class Ext;

template <class T>
void fun(const Ext<T>&);

template <class T>
class Ext {
    template<typename U> //added this template<typename U>
    friend void fun(const Ext<U>&); 
    //added this friend template declaration
    template <class U>
    friend void fun2(const typename Ext<U>::Inner& i);  
   private:
    class Inner;

    Inner* p;
};

template <class T>
void fun2(const typename Ext<T>::Inner&);
  
template <class T>
class Ext<T>::Inner {

    template<typename U>  //added this template<typename U>
    friend void fun(const Ext<U>&);  
    
    template <class U>   //added this template<typename U>
    friend void fun2(const typename Ext<U>::Inner& i);         
 
   private:
    Inner* q; 
    int a;
    Inner() : a(1) {} 
};

template <class T>
void fun2(const typename Ext<T>::Inner& i) {
    std::cout << i.a << std::endl; 
} 
 
template <class T>
void fun(const Ext<T>& e) {
    typename Ext<T>::Inner y;  
    y.a = 3;
    fun2<T>(y);       
}

int main() {
    Ext<int> x;
    fun(x);
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EfroEGz3x)

Now the program works with all compilers.

Comment: yes but if i make fun and fun2 friend template declarations then they are friend of Ext regardless of the template arguments.